# moment.js and October 2021 wierd resuutls

Tags: momentjs

Adding 24 hours to the 31 October 2021, I was aspecting getting the 1st of November

in 2020 was so, but in 2021 is not .... or I did some stupid mistake...

could anyone help me:

```js
console.log("October 2021")
var a = moment("2021103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(23, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
var a = moment("2021103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(24, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
var a = moment("2021103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(25, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);


console.log("October 2020")
var a = moment("2020103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(23, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
var a = moment("2020103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(24, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
var a = moment("2020103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(25, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);

console.log("October 2022")
var a = moment("2022103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(23, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
var a = moment("2022103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(24, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
var a = moment("2022103100", "YYYYMMDDHH").add(25, 'hours').format('YYYYMMDDHH');
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

https://codepen.io/stefanosedano/pen/gOxxora?editors=1011

Comment: Can you point out where the issue is? It is not clear (to me anyway).

Comment: There is something strange with October 31, 2021. unlike 2020 or 2022 by adding 24 hours or 23 hours to October 31 2021, moment.js returns a date with one hour less

Answer (score 1):

Last sunday of october in some timezones has 25 Hours for dst law.

could be your case, try to put 25 hr

Answer (score 0):

From [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-dst-end-2021.html)
**End of DST in Europe 2021:** On Sunday, October 31, 2021, clocks will be set back 1 hour in most of Europe as Daylight Saving Time (DST) ends.

I assume you are in Spain so October 31, 2021 was a day with 25 hours. At 3 am local time (1:00 UTC) the clocks are set back 1 hour, to 2 am.

October 31, 2020 was a Saturday, hence no problem.